# Loading the table to R very quickly

Tags: r

Let say that I found such table on the internet and I want to load it to R. How can I do it quickly ?

```
Name     No1   No2   No3   No4  No5   No6   No7   
Gregg    4     11    53    11    0    23    52   
Monica   2     1     31    6     2    1      4
Finn     54    3     13    2    165   53     3   
Elijah   1     43    31    16    5    2      1
```

Comment: Is it really in plain text like that or is it an HTML table?

Comment: +1 and I would be really interested why this has been downvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this :

```
df <- read.table(text="Name     No1   No2   No3   No4  No5   No6   No7   
Gregg    4     11    53    11    0    23    52   
Monica   2     1     31    6     2    1      4
Finn     54    3     13    2    165   53     3   
Elijah   1     43    31    16    5    2      1  ", header=TRUE)
```